# Find file modes in console (fuzzy completion)

Tags: linux, bash, console, terminal

Is there any way to get in the console a functionality like ido find file mode for Emacs?

For those not familiar with it is a way to recuresevely find files with autocomplete functionality (with no need of TAB), I think is can be also called fuzzy completion.

You can see a video of what I'm talking about here:
[Find File in Emacs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cvEJHU3SGk)

Comment: 1. Do you know how to use wild card file specs with the find -file option? 2. Did you know you can do ls \*/\*/file\*?  3. Are you saying you want to use the console, and get an autocomplete feature that can scan down subdirs?

Comment: @"Fernando Diaz Garrido" : Also, I found the demo to be hard to parse. Others viewers be warned, most of the action is happening at the bottom of the screen. I had to go to full screen mode. I saw a lot of key strokes, passing over files that weren't of interest. Wild carding is best! ;-). 4. I think you're going to have to find the source code to ido, and see how you can integrate it into bash. (I think bash supports such feature expansion, but now certain). Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've started work on a bash completion module to do (non-recursive) fuzzy completion. It currently works, but with a few quirks I'm trying to iron out.

https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion

Usage:

```
source fuzzy_bash_completion
source fuzzy_log_setup_functions

# easy-setup for many commands if you use the bash_completion package
fuzzy_replace_filedir_xspec
# or, for individual commands:
fuzzy_setup_for_command cd # set up fuzzy completion for cd
```

More usage info on the github page.

Comment: Hey @mgalgs, thought I'd say, "Hi" and let you know that I updated my answer below to reference fzf in case you unaware of it/were interested taking a look :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read up on how to extend the completion behaviour within bash here: [Programmable-Completion-Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins)

EDIT:

Since writing this answer, (all those years ago!) I can now point to [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) as a program that does this at the command line. Implemented in Rust, it delivers what the OP was looking for.

Plenty of YouTube videos on this, here's a link to one of them, [Intro to fzf](https://youtu.be/F8dgIPYjvH8?t=64) by  Andrew Courter